# Ajax returning as error when successful

Tags: javascript, ajax

the following code returns a response to the error part of the ajax. What am I doing wrong?

JS code:

```
    var firstName = $('input[name=first]').val(),
        lastName = $('input[name=last]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "add-user.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            first: firstName,
            last: lastName

        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $dbConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");
    $stmt = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO pokemon (firstName, lastName) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstName, $lastName);

    $firstName = $_POST['first'];
    $lastName = $_POST['last'];

    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="addUser" class="user-input">
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="first"></label> <br>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last"></label> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="user-submit">
</form>
```

Submits to the database fine but the response comes back as an error:

```
Object {readyState: 0, status: 0, statusText: "error"}
```

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: `readyState: 0` ... you are using an http server, right? not using `file://` URI but `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Yes I'm using http://

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the variables first.

```
 <?php
  $firstName = $_POST['first'];
  $lastName = $_POST['last'];
  $dbConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");
  $stmt = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO pokemon (firstName, lastName) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstName, $lastName);



  $stmt->execute();

?>
```

make ajax like this

```
$("#userForm").submit(function(e){
    url: "add-user.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success:function(data){console.log(data);}
});
```

html

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="addUser" id="userForm" class="user-input">
<label>First Name: <input type="text" name="first"></label> <br>
<label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last"></label> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="user-submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Returned: 
    Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Comment: Check the updated code. Just send the data as plain. JSON is not required.

Comment: Can you provide html of your form? Maybe there could be another method that I can think of

Comment: Post updated with HTML

Comment: Check the update code

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that php understands JSON out of the box -- it doesn't.

You will need to either convert your ajax to send "url-encoded" data, or get php to parse the body (that contains the JSON string).